# XSL substring with in another string

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Results.xsl"?>
  <TestCase>
    <Details>

    <platform>Windows 7-Firefox\prod</platform>

    </Details>
  </TestCase>
```

I need to retrieve Windows 7 Firefox prod as individual strings im able to retrieve all the strings except "Firefox", please help to to retrieve it

My XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>


       <OS><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(TestCase/Details/platform, '-')"/></OS>
<inst><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '\')"/></inst>

<brow><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '\'),'-')"> </brow>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this backwards (and missing a closing!):

```
<brow><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '\'),'-')"> </brow>
```

It should be:

```
<brow>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(TestCase/Details/platform, '-'),'\')"/> 
</brow>
```